# CSV file unable to be found

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code to read csv file then take an item number in the csv and search for it in a website, then give me URL of the results.

The issue is that it is unable to find the csv file.

Here's the code:

```
url = 'https://khusheimstore.com/?wc-ajax=aws_action'
urlist= []

with open ('./book1', mode='r') as file:
    csvfile = csv.reader(file)

    for line in csvfile:
        myobj = { 'keyword': line }
        resultlist= requests.post(url, data=myobj)
        for result in resultlist.product:
            urlist.append(result.url)
```

This the error message I received, although the file is there in the same folder of the code!

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './book1'
```

Comment: Is it maybe called "book1.csv"? `with open('book1.csv') as file`

Comment: Add the extension too, it might work. You can also add the whole path

Comment: @not_speshal yes the name of the file is "book1.csv",  is it wrong ?

Comment: You need to **run** this script in the same folder as the CSV file, not only put them in the same folder. By default, your terminal isn't in the same folder. Otherwise, use the absolute path, not a relative one

Comment: @ZainabAlkamal - You need to specify ".csv" in your code. You haven't done that. Use exactly: `with open("book1.csv") as file`

Answer (score 0):

you might missed adding extension .csv in file name try this

```py
url = 'https://khusheimstore.com/?wc-ajax=aws_action'
urlist= []

    
with open ('./book1.csv', mode='r') as file:
    csvfile = csv.reader(file)

    for line in csvfile:    
        myobj = { 'keyword': line }
        resultlist= requests.post(url, data=myobj)
        for result in resultlist.product:
            urlist.append(result.url)
```

Comment: I added it like this but i still get the same error